# Does anyone have example code of using scipy.stats.distributions?

Tags: python, scipy

I am struggling to figure out how to use the scipy.distributions package and wondered if anyone could post some example code for me.  It appears to do everything I need, I just can't figure out how to use it.

I need to generate two distributions, one log-normal and one poisson.  I know the variance and lambda for each.

Links to resources would work just as well.

Comment: [Here are all the scipy.stats distributions PDFs with example code.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559471/2087463)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you mean the distributions in `scipy.stats`. To create a distribution, generate random variates and calculate the pdf:

Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  4 2008, 21:48:13) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> from scipy.stats import poisson, lognorm
>>> myShape = 5;myMu=10
>>> ln = lognorm(myShape)
>>> p = poisson(myMu)
>>> ln.rvs((10,)) #generate 10 RVs from ln
array([  2.09164812e+00,   3.29062874e-01,   1.22453941e-03,
         3.80101527e+02,   7.67464002e-02,   2.53530952e+01,
         1.41850880e+03,   8.36347923e+03,   8.69209870e+03,
         1.64317413e-01])
>>> p.rvs((10,)) #generate 10 RVs from p
array([ 8,  9,  7, 12,  6, 13, 11, 11, 10,  8])
>>> ln.pdf(3) #lognorm PDF at x=3
array(0.02596183475208955)
```

Other methods (and the rest of the `scipy.stats` documentation) can be found at the new [SciPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) site.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some sample code: [Probability distributions in SciPy](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/07/20/probability-distributions-scipy/)