# Python: Generate random values from empirical distribution

Tags: python, statistics

In Java, I usually rely on the [org.apache.commons.math3.random.EmpiricalDistribution](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/EmpiricalDistribution.html) class to do the following:

- Derive a probability distribution from observed data.
- Generate random values from this distribution.

Is there any Python library that provides the same functionality? It seems like [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.resample](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.resample.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.resample) does something similar, but I'm not sure if it implements the same procedure as the Java type I'm familiar with.

Comment: I think the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485076/does-anyone-have-example-code-of-using-scipy-stats-distributions/485233#485233) has what you're looking for.

Comment: @Kevin: the linked answer doesn't work for this case, because it assumes you already know the analytical form of your distribution, whereas this question is looking for something non-parametric.

Answer (score 7):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# This represents the original "empirical" sample -- I fake it by
# sampling from a normal distribution
orig_sample_data = np.random.normal(size=10000)

# Generate a KDE from the empirical sample
sample_pdf = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(orig_sample_data)

# Sample new datapoints from the KDE
new_sample_data = sample_pdf.resample(10000).T[:,0]

# Histogram of initial empirical sample
cnts, bins, p = plt.hist(orig_sample_data, label='original sample', bins=100,
                         histtype='step', linewidth=1.5, density=True)

# Histogram of datapoints sampled from KDE
plt.hist(new_sample_data, label='sample from KDE', bins=bins,
         histtype='step', linewidth=1.5, density=True)

# Visualize the kde itself
y_kde = sample_pdf(bins)
plt.plot(bins, y_kde, label='KDE')
plt.legend()
plt.show(block=False)
```

[image: resulting plot]

`new_sample_data` should be drawn from roughly the same distribution as the original data (to the degree that the KDE is a good approximation to the original distribution).

Comment: This is not the correct way to draw random sample representing original distribution. A proper method would be some kind of CDF transform.

Comment: @Zanam: what kinds of problems would you expect from this method? I'm no stats expert, so I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Just the fact that empirical distribution usually never fit any standard distributions that we know of.

Comment: @Zanam: the only assumption I've made is that the original data distribution can be reasonably fit by a Gaussian-smoothed KDE -- I'm not assuming that it follows any particular standard distribution.

Comment: @Zanam can you please elaborate on the point you are trying to make?